# Inserir no HTML e com funções do AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Gente to com problema quando insiro um `HTML` que contém um módulo `ng`, e quando clico para executar não acontece nada. Veja o Código:

```
//HomeCtrl.js
module.exports = function($scope) {
    // Create Note
    $scope.create = function(e) {
        var value = $scope.inputNote,
            $element = $(e.target).closest('.task-container').find('.tasks-list');

        $element.prepend(
            ' <li class="task-item"> '
                + '<div class="task-check">'
                    + '<label>'
                        + '<input type="checkbox">'
                        + '<span class="text"></span>'
                    + '</label>'
                + '</div>'
                + '<div class="task-state">'
                    + '<span class="label label-orange">ATIVA</span>'
                + '</div>'
                + '<div class="task-time">'
                    + '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="#!" ng-click="remove($event)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remover</a>'
                + '</div>'
                + '<div class="task-body">'+ value +'</div>'
            + '</li>'
            );
    };
    // Button Remove
    $scope.remove = function(e) {
        var $element = $(e.target).closest('li');
        $element.remove();
    };
};
```

quando eu digito em um `input` e da um ENTER, ele envia para o `ng-submit="create($event)"` e executando a inserção do `HTML`, o problema é o `button`  que tem a função `ng-click="remove($event)"` e não executa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa compilar o HTML para que ele seja reconhecido pelo Angular. Exemplo:

```
//HomeCtrl.js
module.exports = function($scope, $compile) {
    // Create Note
    $scope.create = function(e) {
        var value = $scope.inputNote,
            $element = $(e.target).closest('.task-container').find('.tasks-list');

        $element.prepend($compile( // Compila o bloco a seguir pelo Angular
            ' <li class="task-item"> '
                + '<div class="task-check">'
                    + '<label>'
                        + '<input type="checkbox">'
                        + '<span class="text"></span>'
                    + '</label>'
                + '</div>'
                + '<div class="task-state">'
                    + '<span class="label label-orange">ATIVA</span>'
                + '</div>'
                + '<div class="task-time">'
                    + '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="#!" ng-click="remove($event)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remover</a>'
                + '</div>'
                + '<div class="task-body">'+ value +'</div>'
            + '</li>'
            )($scope));
    };
    // Button Remove
    $scope.remove = function(e) {
        var $element = $(e.target).closest('li');
        $element.remove();
    };
};
```

Comment: +1. Lembro quando eu tinha penado pra descobrir isso :\

Comment: Eu gostei quando você falou do `$compile`, mas percebi na pesquisa que ele é aplicado em uma `directive` e não no `controller`, quando executei às mudanças aconteceu este erro: `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'scope' is required`

Comment: @iLeonardoCarvalho Correto, eu esqueci de adicionar um parâmetro ao final. Resposta corrigida, obrigado por mencionar o erro!

Comment: Funcionou corretamente, agora o `ng`é reconhecido, mas é correto eu inserir um `HTML` no `controller` ou de alguns exemplos falando para inserir no `directive`? Pois posso ver como converter este `controller` para uma `directive` mas quero aplicar às boas práticas de programação.

Comment: @iLeonardoCarvalho Se for uma *unit of work* bem definida, vale a pena isolar em uma diretiva. Caso não, não se preocupe tanto com isso; uma das atribuições do controller é coordenar a exibição de conteúdo.

Comment: @OnoSendai vou verificar este assunto abordado, neste cenário é somente a inserção de um `HTML` e a retirada do elemento construído pelo um router o `ui-router` e modularizando o código usando o `browserify`, creio que ainda seja pouco para um sistema complexo mas agradeço pelo apontamento do artigo.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que falta um `$scope.$apply` no final da função, sem isso não vai passar no `$digest` do angular, e por isso os ng-* não são reconhecidos.

Da uma olhada na seção do [$digest()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) que é onde começa a falar sobre isso.

```
$scope.create = function(e) {
    var value = $scope.inputNote,
        $element = $(e.target).closest('.task-container').find('.tasks-list');

    $element.prepend(
        ' <li class="task-item"> '
            + '<div class="task-check">'
                + '<label>'
                    + '<input type="checkbox">'
                    + '<span class="text"></span>'
                + '</label>'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="task-state">'
                + '<span class="label label-orange">ATIVA</span>'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="task-time">'
                + '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="#!" ng-click="remove($event)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remover</a>'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="task-body">'+ value +'</div>'
        + '</li>'
        );
    $scope.$apply();
};
```

Comment: Eu vou ver nos documentos do Angular sobre o `$digest()`, mas quando executei ele me retorna assim: `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress`, devo declarar o $apply na função do controller?